# How to analyse the sound of Motor

Tags: matlab, continuous-signals, signal-detection

I have a motor, that I want to analyse, using its sound, so I can  its 'character' I was using the the simple fft, and figured out, that it wouldn't help, so I tried the order analysis, at least I incremented the speed of the motor and I can say it in spectrogram like here:

[image]

My question isn't about codes but about theory, what are the methods that I can use to analyse the sound of motor? 
Thanks for any help ! 
link : [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894679/how-to-implement-the-order-analysis-in-matlab)

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by "analyse"? Which kind of information do you want to extract? Is this a classification or recognition problem (maybe recognising a specific defect, given a pre-existing database of recordings for which the defect is known?)

Comment: say I'get multiples motors ,and I want to compare the way they'Re runnning how can do that based on their sounds. Or let say you've a motor that is running and you hear anomalies , how can you  find that out using  the sound and a analyse method !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using the STFT (or spectrogram) as you already did is a good start. Try to change the parameters of your STFT, i.e. window size and frame shift until you are able to detect certain frequencies and their repetitions.

This is an example for a decelerating car on the highway. The inertial sensor (not a microphone) was placed at the axle:

[image: STFT of decelerating car]

Comment: thansk for you answer, but the time axis is compose of of 10sec parts with  incrementing the rpm

Comment: After correcting the parameters, you will probably see an image with a step-shape. Your frequency and periodic repetitions will be visible.