# The order analysis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, continuous-signals

Can anybody tell me how to calculate the order analysis / spectrum of a signal? I've been searching in vain. I want to use MATLAB to analyse the signal / sound of a motor.

For more information about the order analysis - here is an [example](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372416A-01/svtconcepts/intro_ord_ana/)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "order analysis"? What do you want to find out about the motor and what kind of signal do you have?

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: And how is this question different from that one: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/how-to-analyse-the-sound-of-motor? I think you've already received quite a useful answer there.

Comment: in the other  question I'm asking about other methodes, here I'm asking about the order analysis and how to implement it

Comment: Order analysis is an important method used in mechanical engineering. It helps identify harmonics that are generated by the various reciprocating parts in an engine. The Fourier transform isn't always useful for this. It looks interesting but a Google search doesn't bring up any theory, just superficial descriptions.

Comment: @MackTuesday do you know how can this be calculated ?

Comment: I don't really know anything about it. I'm guessing that you run the engine at various speeds to study the relationship between speed and harmonic content. My approach would be to have an accurate measurement of the curve of speed v. time, and use that to resample the output from the engine and a varying sample rate, then take the FFT of that. I have no idea whether or not it would work.

Comment: Order Analysis is not simply some kind of algorithm that is spitting out a number and you are done. It's a tool for looking into your signal, and you need to understand first what are you looking at. Start here: [click](http://www.bksv.co.uk/Support/~/media/UnitedKingdom/FAQ%20Downloads/Order%20Analysis.ashx), [click](http://bit.ly/PMJHWG), and check out the book of Scheffer and Girdhar: Practical Machinery Vibration Analysis and Predictive Maintenance.